# Changing label text inside method

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using delegation to pass back information from a view controller.
This is the method

```
 func writeValueBack(value: String) {
  self.label.text = value
}
```

The function gets called and all is great apart from the label doesn't update.

The label has a value and is not returning nil, I checked with this line

```
println(self.label.text)
```

It prints the value of 'value'

So that means that the label's text is being set to 'value' but it's not updating.

I even tried using the main thread but no luck

```
func writeValueBack(value: String) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.label.text = value
    })
}
```

I just don't know what the problem is.

Any help would be great.

Protocol:

```
protocol writeValueBackDelegate {
func writeValueBack(value: String)
}
```

EDIT:
Code for my view controller:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  DelegateTesting
//
//  Created by Alex Catchpole on 30/11/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Alex Catchpole. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, writeValueBackDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "MainSegue" {
        var vc = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
        vc.labelText = textField.text
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}

func writeValueBack(value: String) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.label.text = value
    })
}


@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.label.text = textField.text
}

@IBAction func segue(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("MainSegue", sender: self)

}
```

}

Second ViewController source:

```
//
//  SecondViewController.swift
//  DelegateTesting
//
//  Created by Alex Catchpole on 30/11/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Alex Catchpole. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

var labelText: String!
var delegate: writeValueBackDelegate? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    label.text = labelText

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
    label.text = textField.text
}


@IBAction func segueBack(sender: AnyObject) {
    var editedText = label.text
    performSegueWithIdentifier("SecondSegue", sender: self)
    if (delegate != nil) {
        delegate?.writeValueBack(editedText)
        println("working")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is `self.label` a `UILabel` or a `UIButton`?

Comment: It's a UILabel not a button.

Comment: Just to add, nothing will update. I've tried setting the text of a textField in the same method and nothing. The value gets applied but the UI element doesn't update.

Comment: This should work. At what point are you are calling this? Maybe the UILabel is subsequently recreated or reset.

Comment: Check the frame size of the label.

Comment: @Clafou Added my ViewController source.

Comment: @Swipesight The default text of the label is "label" and because the function isn't changing the text, it stays as "label" so the frame hasn't changed.

Comment: Does your button action, self.label.text = textField.text, work?

Comment: Yes it does. It turns out that If I call the func 'writeValueBack' in the view did load and pass in a value such as "hello" the label will display the text, it's only when I call the function from my second view controller it won't display although the value is stored.

Comment: I've add all my code to see if the problem lies in my delegate.

Comment: Your problem is that you're creating a new controller with your segue (SecondSegue), not going back to the first controller. If you're going to use a segue to go back, you have to use an unwind segue.

Comment: Ok I'll try it but that sounds promising.

Comment: rdelmar is right, and given that you are using a segue you could get rid of the delegate altogether (you get a reference to your second view controller in your segue method, so you can grab your data there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your second view controller, which as rdelmar pointed out creates a new instance of your first view controller instead of navigating back to the original instance.

To fix this, you could use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion` instead of performing your second segue. But an unwind segue would lead to simpler code, and can be achieved by adding this to your first view controller:

```
@IBAction func unwindFromSecond(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let secondViewController = unwindSegue.sourceViewController as? SecondViewController {
        label.text = secondViewController.label.text
        // Or whatever you need to retrieve data from the second controller
    }
}
```

Then in your storyboard create an unwind segue from the second view controller. For example if you have a Dismiss button, control-drag from this button to the Exit icon in your second view controller scene and choosing `unwindFromSecond`. For detailed steps see the answer to this other question: [What are Unwind segues for and how do you use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them)

You can now remove the `writeValueBackDelegate` declaration and associated variables, the `writeValueBack` method and the second view controller's `segueBack` method